# uiactivityindicator when page is loading

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

How can I show an uiactivityindicator when I click a cell in my tableview as sometimes it takes a few moments for it to get pushed to the next view since it's getting information from the internet.

I have successfully done it for my uiwebview but just stuck on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Which view do you want to show activity indicator? The one with table view or the one being pushed?

Comment: @TheBlack: I would like to show it in the tableview. Do you know how? Thanks.

Comment: I assume you're adding activity indicator in didSelectRowForIndex UITableViewDelegate method... You should add activity indicator as subview of table view, fire async http request, kill activity indicator when request finishes and push new VC. If you're using sync http request, it will block UI thread and you wont see activity indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-(void)viewDidLoad {
webPage.self = delegate;
indicator.hidesWhenStopped = TRUE;
}

–(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[indicator startAnimating];
}

–(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[indicator stopAnimating];
}

Comment: Hi, it's not a webview i'm trying to put the indicator in. It's in the tableviews in my navigationcontroller. Do you know how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewdDidAppear:YES];
[indicator startAnimating];
NSTimer* timerLoad = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(stopIndicator) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)stopIndicator {
[indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

I think this give you a time for load your tableView

Put it in navigation controller

```
indicator.frame = CGRect(11,130,37,37);
[navBar addSubview:indicator];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rather perform the fetching data in the next view controller on a separate thread (in background) so that it doesn't blocks the UI. And Until the data fetching is done, show activity indicator there.

Answer (score 0):

(void)viewDidLoad {

//We have a NIB file in play here, so I dropped the loadView here.  Just make sure that your loadView is not getting called twice!

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[self loadView];
```

}

- (void)loadView {

  UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
  self.view = contentView;

  CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
  webFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
  myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
  myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
  myWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
  myWebView.delegate = self;
  [self.view addSubview: myWebView];

  [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xyz.com/"]]];

  activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
  activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
  activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
  [self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];
  }
- (void)dealloc {
  [activityIndicator release];
  [myWebView release];
      [super dealloc];
  }

## pragma mark WEBVIEW Methods

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
  {
  // starting the load, show the activity indicator in the status bar

  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
  [activityIndicator startAnimating];
  }
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
  {
  // finished loading, hide the activity indicator in the status bar

  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
  [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
  }
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
  {
  // load error, hide the activity indicator in the status bar

  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

  // report the error inside the webview

  NSString* errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"
  Error
  Your request %@",
                           error.localizedDescription];
  [myWebView loadHTMLString:errorString baseURL:nil];

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are adding here. Is this a solution or an additional problem?